# Archive file system and mount read-only later

Tags: backup, archive

I have some hard drive whose contents I’d like to archive. It should be possible to mount it read-only later. Ideally it should be possible to mount a subdirectory instead of the whole archived file system.

The problem with a blockwise copy of the hard drive (e.g. using `dd`) is that the size of the image can be much larger than the amount of used space on the file system.

The problem with copying the files itself to the backup medium is that the integrity of the files is hard to enforce and it’s not possible to prevent that the copied files are executed without either changing the metadata of these files or preventing execution of all files on the backup medium.

The problem with archive formats like `tar` or `dar` is that it’s not possible to mount (parts of) the archive later. (For `tar` archives it seems to be possible, but it’s impractical because the complete archive has to be read sequentially.)

Is there a solution that doesn’t have these limitations?

Comment: `tar` can be mount by fuse. Once you can read the code, you can always execute the code. Filesystem permission is only meaningful for a running kernel. For integrity protection, use digital signature technology, you can google that.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 It’s true that there are tools to mount .tar archives, however the format is not really made for it because the archive file has to be read sequentially to list files or access some specific file.

Comment: If you know that very well, it's strange you didn't come up with the filesystem image solution, like squashfs. Notice that unless the filesystem specifically support that, mount the non-root directory of the filesystem can't be done in one syscall. It has to be a bind mount

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I’ve added the limitation (that the complete archive has to be read sequentially) to the question. Do you want to add the suggestion of squashfs as an answer?